# Android EditText doesn't show the Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a screen with three EditText's, and one of then, the first one, in the top of the screen doesn't call the keyboard when I click on it. I'm not using an AVD, I'm using my own device, and tested in others devices and same result.

I'll put the screen here and the xml codes...
there is nothing diferent between the EditTexts, just position.
To make an input in that EditText I need to select one of the EditText above, and then the keyboard shows up. At least it doesn't hide when I select the first EditText again.
I've already try the setFocus(true) and it doesn't solve my problem.
please, help me!

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SaldoCadastro" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTituloReg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Saldo Banco"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvErroSenha1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTituloReg"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Insert on the field below how much you have in your bank." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvErroSenha1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvErroSenha1"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="Insert on the field below how much is your credit card limit." />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSaldo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvErroSenha1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCartaoLimite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etCartaoLimite"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etCartaoLimite"
    android:text="About your credt card how much you&apos;ve spent already." />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCartao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btRegisterSaldo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etCartao"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etCartao"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="Register" />
```

Comment: I could't show the image cause I don't have enough reputation, sorry fellows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    ......
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: what actually this attribute do.

Comment: Downvote because it didn't help understanding the problem at all. Just saying "do this" and that's it shouldn't be upvoted even if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `layout.xml` if your layout implement `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` remove it

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from xml:

```
<requestFocus />
```

else in code you can add this:

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Comment: should I add clearFocus() on all of the EditTexts or just in the one is "broken" ?

Comment: Whereever it is not working :). You can add to all. I think in your xml you added <requestFocus /> to one only which got broken.

Comment: yes I did...
try to make it work, read some tutorials and other answer and they said that it would solve my problem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please check your `AndroidManifest.xml` activity
and make some changes there like this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

in activity where of this layout example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.a.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" // This will make your keyboard work
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you mean that when you start your activity, the soft_keyboard show up?if this, what you do just add this code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, for example like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.fortrun.testcrashlytics.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, using android EditText instead of my custom EditText solved the problem .