# Android ListView with EditText loses focus when the keyboard displays. Keyboards appear randomly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am an iOS developer, and I have been given task to fix this.
After digging and googling, I have no idea what to do.

We have this screen:

[image]

This screen is Activity with custom Fragment, containing ListView fed by ArrayAdapter.
The adapter produces views by getView it seems.
Every row has seven EditText controls.

Problem 1:
When screen is shown first time, and you tap on any EditText, nothing happens.
Why?
When you tap second time, and any subsequent time, focus works, keyboard appears, and you can type.

Problem 2:
This is hard to describe. On some devices, tapping any EditText causes keyboards to switch between some numeric and alphanumeric types, and this goes on and on and then stops.
Why?

After trying various stuff:
[getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection warning on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android)
[onClick event is not triggering | Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790573/onclick-event-is-not-triggering-android)
[Android EditText doesn't show the Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347423/android-edittext-doesnt-show-the-keyboard)
...

I have no idea what is the problem.

According to one of SO posts, you should not have both onClick and onTouch, yet here they are.
Why?

```
        editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.requestFocus();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((EditText) v).selectAll();
        }
    });
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)v).getText().toString());
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
                String result = df.format(amount);
                ((EditText)v).setText(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am still digging, commenting out various code, but I am in dark, please help.

Whole code: https://gist.github.com/MartinBergerDX/473c47b008b6b0570466794f221eca31

Update 1:

I have removed all listeners, onTouch, onFocus, and text watchers.

And this is still happening:

[image]

Update 2:

It seems this is related to keyboard covering ListView. Not sure why, but when I set less than 10 items in data source, keyboard does not cover content and ping pong effect does not happen.

Comment: from your question its unclear what exactly you want to achieve here. why you want to use onClick and onTouch at the same time?

Comment: @Jacks This app is already written by some devs. Issue that is happening on this screen is when user taps on any EditText, keyboard appear, then alternate between Numeric and Alpha Numeric input mode by itself. I want to be able to tap on EditText, enter a number, tap on next EditText, enter a number, tap on next EditText, enter a number without keyboards playing ping pong.

Comment: for this you can temporarily comment out all the events related to "editText" and try running once. it should work. the problem here is because of the extra events being added to the editText

Comment: @Jacks Yes. And it seems it is being done by setText calls. Does this calls fire more events? I have added gist with whole code, without my modifications.

Comment: i can see 4 different events are registered with the editText. nothing more.and setOnFocusChangeListener set the text again, that could be the cause for ping pong effect

Comment: @Jacks So I have removed everything from those EditTexts, and strange ping pong is still happening. Please see gif I have attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have xml for this view or you are generating these edittext programatically if you have xml then for each edit text do **android:inputType="number"** if you are generating these editext programatically then do this for each **edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);** with this only number key willl be shown for user input next just add addTextChangedListener to each editText

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//handle your changes here
    }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

**Update**

Android ListView with EditText loses focus when the keyboard displays The issue is when you have a ListView with input capable fields that displays the soft keyboard on focus, the EditText loses its focus for the first time but the second time it just works fine. The reason it happens is all the views are getting rendered again, so the EditText field object in the item row that used to be focused is now a completely different object. **android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"** in your ListView and **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** for your activity in the app Manifest

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/productList" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search" 
android:layout_below="@+id/search" 
android:padding="5dp" 
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>
```

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Reference https://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-edittext-listview-loses-focus.html

Comment: Input type in xml is numberDecimal. Even when I do not attach any listeners, I get ping pong effect. Any idea why?

Comment: did you try this on multiple devices? or only on emulator? and did u try writing the code in java file for setting input type to number?

Comment: Tried on one Android tablet and Emulator. I have tried setting input type to number. Same effect. It seems this has something to do with not hiding keyboard after tapping to other EditText... I am lost.

Comment: I do understand that you have commented all listener but just want to confirm did u comment this line setListeners(vh, stavkaHelper) ?

Comment: Yes I have. Now I have found something out. It seems this issue happens when keyboard covers ListView. Is there some behaviour on Android when keyboard covers ListView?

Comment: I confirm that this has solved ping pong effect. This has probably saved me some 20 hours of work. Thank you for this. Maybe you should update your answer. This fixes ping pong effect, which this question is about.

Comment: More questions: on Android, in getView, do I add listeners on creation in "if (convertView == null) {" block, or after? Do I need to clear them every time getView is called? What about Text Watcher? Does he need to be detached and reattached?

Comment: if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
          }   // next you can write your code no need to clear them

Comment: ListView attempts to reuse view objects in order to improve performance and avoid a lag in response to user scrolls. To take advantage of this feature, check if the convertView provided to getView(...) is null before creating or inflating a new view object. See Making ListView Scrolling Smooth for more ways to ensure a smooth user experience. --- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203668/discussion-between-manoj-mohanty-and-martin-berger).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is useful for you:
[How can I detect a click in an onTouch listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831395/how-can-i-detect-a-click-in-an-ontouch-listener)

Try deleting onClick and using onTouch only, wish it helps.